# Play data while downloading

Tags: macos, swift, alamofire

I am trying do play songs from soundcloud, which is working fine for one exception: when the response handler is called, the download of the file is allready complete. I'd like to start playing the file directly after the download started, but i have no clue how to access the data before the response handler gets called. Accessing the data ln the progress handler would be nice, but i need a hint on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you write your own download code using NSURLConnection and 
`initWithRequest:delegate:startImmediately:`, the delegate methods (e.g. 
`connection:didReceiveData:`) will be called as the data becomes available.

You risk running out of data if you try to play the sound as it is downloaded. You should probably implement a buffering system where you download enough extra data for several seconds of playback before you start playing. That way you can smooth over short "stutters" in the download.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. This looks like it will work, but is there no "alamofire-way" of doing it?

Comment: I have no idea. I've only used Alamo fire a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you at least two options to perform what you want:
 1. [AVPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/index.html) supports playing a file from http. If you download a static file - you can just ask a player to stream over http.
 2. You can download a small chunks of file (5 MB at once, for example) and append them to the result file or write directly into memory buffer. You can download a file chunk of specified size by just adding a `Content-Range` header with an offset you need. (see [RFC, 14.16 Content-Range](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) for more specific info). This method requires server to support partial downloads, but in nowadays it is harder to find a sever that does not support this =) Alamofire easily allows you to do that.

Comment: The Soundcloud API works like this: you send a GET request with the unique song id + your client id or auth token to soundcloud, and the response contains the song data. I tried using avplayer, but there is no url available, only data. Because of that i am forced to use avaudioplayer, which does not support streaming. In addition, i cannot download the file part by part, because soundcloud only accepts a selected range of parameters. What i would find most usefull, is a way to access the data in the progress handler, but i am not sure if thats possible.