# Start playing remote mp3 before entire file has downloaded

Tags: swift, audio, swiftui

I'm building an audio player for iOS using Swift and SwiftUI. I want to be able to start playing a remote mp3 before the file is completely downloaded. And of course once the entire file has downloaded I don't want to have to download it again.

There's a third party library ([CachingPlayerItem](https://github.com/neekeetab/CachingPlayerItem)) that promises to do just this but it's a project with only two contributors and no updates in more than a year. It also relies on AVPlayer, which I think means I'm stuck with the default AVPlayer UI?

An idea I picked up here on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30698043/98374) is to download the remote file in chunks (by setting the `Content-Range` header on the http request).

Using this idea I could download the first five minutes or so of the remote audio, and start playing that. In the meanwhile I start downloading the complete file and when that completes I stop the playing of the short file and start playing the complete file from the position where I stopped playing the short file.

Is this a good idea or is there a better route?

Comment: “which I think means I'm stuck with the default AVPlayer UI” Unclear what that means. AVPlayer has no UI.

Comment: I'm new at this. I think got that misconception from Apples docs "AVPlayer: An object that provides the interface to control the player’s transport behavior.", but I guess they didn't mean visual interface? How about the idea to download few minutes of audio, start playing that and in the meanwhile download the entire file? Do you think it's a good approach?

Comment: Personally I think your reasons for rejecting https://github.com/neekeetab/CachingPlayerItem were all of them meaningless.

Comment: Ok I’ll have another look at it.